# php preg_replace 100% becomes 100;%

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have worked on this for a while without success.  So I am asking for help.

What I have:

I have an array of various patterns I am looking for so I can replace them.  All of the other items in the array work without a problem.  Only one of these replacement strings does something I've not seen before.

The string is:

```
width_(\d+\w+)=width: $1;
```

When this is broken apart on the equal sign via explode:

```
$a = explode( '=', $replacement_string );
```

This becomes:

```
$a[0] = "width(\d+\w+)";
```

and

```
$a[1] = "width: $1;";
```

This is then tested against the incoming string.

```
$a = preg_replace( "/$a[0]/i", "$a[1]", $incoming_string );
```

Now the "I have no idea why it is doing this" part. If the incoming string is

```
"width_100px"
```

I get back

```
"width: 100px;"
```

But if the incoming string is

```
"width_100%"
```

I get back

```
"width: 100;%"
```

The weird thing is - if I just got back

```
"width: 100;"
```

I could understand it.  The "%" matched the semicolon(;).  But this puts the semicolon in AND the percent sign.  It is just that they are reversed.  I have even tried looking to see if there is a percent sign and changing it to

```
"width_100\%"
```

But that did not change what it comes out as.

I also just tried the "%%" instead of just one "%".  Still comes out as

```
width: 100;%
```

Any help appreciated.

ANSWERED:

The answer to this conundrum is that the "\w" part of the regular expression does **NOT** match the percent sign (%) because \w is only [a-zA-Z0-9_] (as shown by Uby below.  Since all of these strings are broken up in to separate requests, the width_100% is all by itself so by changing what it is looking for to (\d+(.*)) (as per Chris85's suggestion below) - this catches the number (in this case 100) as well as the percent sign thus allowing me to then convert this to "width: 100%;".

Thank you to both Chris and Uby for their help.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to put them on.  They are in the original code.

$d = preg_replace( "/$c[0]/i", "$c[1]", $v1 );

I modified the above question.

Comment: Okay, the regex you have doesnt find the `%` so it doesnt replace it. Do you want to replace `%`s if they are present at the end?

Comment: No.  What I am doing is converting CSS information from using underscores to being the actual CSS command.  So like border_1px_solid_white becomes border: 1px solid white.  In this case I converting the width_100% to width: 100%.  So basically I'm generating my CSS on the fly instead of having individual CSS files.  Why?  Because then I don't have to make changes in two locations.  I just modify the HTML with the CSS commands in it and they are auto-generated for me.

Comment: To expand further on this - I can also have a CSS command like w_100% and that get translated to width: 100%.  At least it is supposed to do that but that command also does the width: 100;% instead.  But I thought I'd use the larger one (ie: width_100%) instead because it is easier to read.

Comment: Yes.  More generically - whatever the part is after the number - I want to keep it.  So 100em, 100px, 100%, or 100<whatever> - I should always get the <whatever> back.

Comment: Added an update to answer for accounting to for that, also updated original regex for `em`; take a look at that approach first...

Comment: whats your desired output?

Comment: This has been answered.  The answer is that the percent sign is not a part of the "\w" range.  So it just got tacked on to the end of the string.  I changed it to (\d+(.*)) and now it gets the entire string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see your current issue here: https://regex101.com/r/xD9rG3/1

The `%` isn't matched so it is left in. You can tell the regex to look for `%` or `px` with this expression.

```
width_(\d+(?:px|%))
```

Functional demo:

```
$replacement_string = 'width_(\d+(?:px|%|em))=width: $1;';
$a = explode( '=', $replacement_string );
//$a[0] = "width(\d+\w+)";
//$a[1] = "width: $1;";
$incoming_string = 'width_100%';
$a = preg_replace( "/$a[0]/", "$a[1]", $incoming_string);
echo $a;
```

Regex 101 Demo: https://regex101.com/r/xD9rG3/2

Also you should note that the `\w` includes an underscore so your other regexs may fail. If you want to just look for alpha characters use `[a-zA-Z]+` or add `\d` if you want to include numbers.

Another regex you could use, which I wouldn't recommend would be:

```
width_(\d+.*)
```

This says find `width_` any amount of numbers and then every other character. This could generate invalid css for you. This would match your `whatever the part is after the number` request though..

Comment: That worked! :-)  But I really needed it to be generic so I don't have to put in all of the different ways of saying how the number can be expressed.  But thanks to you I got it working! :-)  I used width_(\d+(.*)).  This caught everything after the number.  But I wouldn't have thought of it if I hadn't seen what you did.  Thanks!!!!! :-)

Comment: Since all of these CSS things are broken up - there shouldn't be a problem using the (.*).  I've written a PHP script that takes a Visual Page HTML file (VP is a VERY old HTML editor but I'm used to it), it removes such things as the <CENTER> command and replaces it with a CSS command on the command above where it was found (so like a TD or BODY command usually). Then it converts them to standard CSS. So like css="center width_100% height_20px" could be a line.  I also put in delimiters into the CSS file so I can add commands if I want and they don't get deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is `\d+\w+` which doesn't include the percentage char `%`. So the replace will simply ignore it and replace just `width_100` with `width: 100;`.

Try replacing `(\d+\w+)` with `(\d+[a-zA-Z0-9_%]+)`

Comment: Yes!  This answer and Chris85's answer above got me to what I needed.  I changed the a-z stuff to just ".*" and it worked.  so width_(\d+(.*)) works.  But I.....oh....the percent sign is not a part of the \w.  NOW I've got it.  :-)  Thanks!

Comment: Be careful with `.*`, it will work just if your original string contains just your "command" (as you defined it) and nothing more. In that case you can get rid of `\d+` too, since `width_(.*)` will work fine.

Comment: I tried to check both your reply and Chris85's reply as the right answer but it only allowed me to do that to one.  So I tried clicking on the up arrow.  It let me do that.  Hope that helps you in the ratings. :-)

Comment: You can choose just 1 right answer (and btw, chris85 one looks really good :P). Thanks for upvoting mine, anyway, it helped.